# i have a problem when making file .env in Vs. the file icon is wrong. help me

Tags: .env

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSG8z.png)

it must be like this. the icon[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NECuD.png)

Answer (score 2):

Install VSCode Great Icons from VsCode>Extensions
The icons will look like below image, and there no problem with your .env file even if you don't install the extensions, it's the other extension which causing this kind of image.

Without any image Extension the default .env file icon will look like settings icon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caused by an icon image extension,
the icons are changed by those kind of extensions.